# how to import jQuery plugin into Typescript file?

Tags: jquery-plugins, typescript

i have a jQuery plugin .js file, and a Typescript file in which i want to use the first plugin. after googling that, maybe i need import library.d.ts into my typescript file like following code, and how about that plugin(slof-slider.js)?

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you have added the following line :

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts"/>
```

You need to tell TypeScript about the functions added by `SlofSlider` (not sure about the name?) e.g. if you want :

```
$('div').slider();
```

to compile you would do something like:

```
interface JQuery {
    slider: Function;
}
```

Comment: should i download jquery.d.ts file and reside it under a certain directory?im confused, cuz i can not find this file online. thanks basarat.

Comment: @paulcheung you can download this file from DefinitelyTyped : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/jquery You can it anywhere, but you will need to adjust the relative path accordingly. Simplest case is to paste it in the same folder : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery-tests.ts#L1

Answer (score 1):

After adding this reference

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts"/>
```

Add the jquery.min library to webpage... that should work fine..